# Access values within a JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object (of objects) that firefox tells me looks like this:

```
Object(8)
​0: Object { name: "Appleby", value: 8670, line_count: 4, … }
​1: Object { name: "Armthorpe", value: 1470, line_count: 3, … }
​2: Object { name: "Blackbrook", value: 300, line_count: 2, … }
​3: Object { name: "Blackpool", value: 600, line_count: 1, … }
```

I would like to extract two arrays from this, a list of the names and values, such as:

```js
myArray['names'] = ["Appleby", "Armthorpe", ...]
myArray['values'] = [8670, 1470, ...]
```

Can you please advise how I can do this?

I have tried using this for in loop:

```js
for(const item in input) 
{
myArray.names.push(item.name); 
myArray.values.push(item.value);
}
```

However, this returns only integers, and not the objects, as shown in this console output:

```
> input = {0: { name: "Appleby", value: 8670, line_count: 4, }, 1:{ name: "Armthorpe", value: 1470, line_count: 3, }, 2: { name: "Blackbrook", value: 300, line_count: 2 }, 3: { name: "Blackpool", value: 600, line_count: 1,}}
< {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}}
> let myArray = {names: [], values: []}
< undefined
> for(const item in input) {myArray.names.push(item.name); myArray.values.push(item.value);}
< 4
> myArray
< {names: Array(4), values: Array(4)}
```

Comment: Use `for...of` instead of `for...in`.

Comment: There's no reason you can't do this with a `for` loop. Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Those integers are the keys and you would then use `mainObject[keyVariable].name` in your `for in` loop to get at the properties you want. The proper thing to do here is to show what you actually tried so others can help you understand why it wasn't working and to help you fix your own attempts

Comment: @charlietfl I have attempted to improve my question based on your feedback. If you previously downvoted this question, would you reconsider based on my effots?

Comment: @Mitya I have attempted to improve my question based on your feedback. If you previously downvoted this question, would you reconsider based on my efforts?

Comment: @gclark18 I didn't downvote. Seems you have your answer. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in your object of objects as inputObject and use this function:

```
/**
* This function converts a JSON object of objects into two separate arrays:
* 1. names 
* 2. values
*/
function myFunction(inputObject) {

  const myArray = { // should be myObject, really.
    names: [],
    values: []
  };


  for(const item of inputObject) {
    myArray.names.push(item.name);
    myArray.values.push(item.value);
  }

  return myArray;
}
```

Comment: `myArray.values,push(item.value)` typo

Comment: There is also `const myArray;` which should be `const myArray = {};`

Comment: @Titus good call, updated my answer to use an object instead of array

Comment: One nitpick is that `myArray` is a misleading name for an object literal that really isn't an array, regardless if OP started it or not

Comment: @charlietfl I agree, this is the chosen variable name of OP, and I respect that.  I will leave a comment